# Emulating Apple Music app's modal background gradient in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, modalviewcontroller

When the Music presents the currently playing song...

It uses a gradient in its background... This would be a good compromise between using the standard background and black opaque background (it doesn't look nice as you can't see the 3D stacking effect anymore)

[image]